# How do i get multiple number strings after brackets [] using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with 2k data as below .I want to get only number values of updr/udrl/imgr/imgl fields as 41110.00 120 996.00 523 with tab separated where updr/updl/imgr/imgl fileds present.

I have tried with single pattern replacement till brackets but after that not able to apply another pattern to get numbers.

```
echo `sed -n 's/^\[.*][^0-9]*[[:space:]]* //p' client_stat.txt > client_stat_onlyData.csv` ; echo `sed -i 's/ /\t/g' client_stat_onlyData.csv`
```

I am getting o/p as like below but i do not want to print udpr/updl/imgr/imgl strings i want to print only number values.

```
updr    48358.00        updl    120     imgr    1015.00 imgl    523
updr    48562.00        updl    120     imgr    1169.00 imgl    523
updr    48305.00        updl    121     imgr    1210.00 imgl    523
updr    48285.00        updl    121     imgr    1135.00 imgl    523
updr    48459.00        updl    121     imgr    1210.00 imgl    523
updr    48246.00        updl    120     imgr    881.00  imgl    523
updr    48439.00        updl    120     imgr    1109.00 imgl    523
```

Number of Connection Count = 1
Creating RSSL connection Host: 192.168.120.1 Port: 14002
UPA server component version: ads3.2.2.L1.linux.tis.rrg 64-bit
Setting rmds connection 0x10a8900
Connection list count is 1
SupportStandby: 0
SupportBatchRequests Initial Open: Yes
SupportBatchRequests Reissue: Yes
SupportBatchClose: Yes
SupportViewRequests: Yes
SupportOptimizedPauseResume: 0

```
[Tue Feb 19 14:42:50.415] updr 41110.00 updl 120 imgr 996.00 imgl 523
    [Tue Feb 19 14:42:51.415] updr 49368.00 updl 121 imgr 845.00 imgl 523

Status Received <388> Status Text: Stale Status for Item REC1000017 Text: F7: Item Preempted
[Tue Feb 19 14:42:52.415] updr 48542.00 updl 121 imgr 1170.00 imgl 523

Status Received <1166> Status Text: Stale Status for Item REC1000410 Text: F7: Item Preempted
[Tue Feb 19 14:42:53.415] updr 47942.00 updl 120 imgr 1133.00 imgl 523

Status Received <1133> Status Text: Stale Status for Item REC1001609 Text: F7: Item Preempted
[Tue Feb 19 14:42:54.415] updr 48513.00 updl 120 imgr 1100.00 imgl 523
```

Comment: A warm welcome to SO, special thanks for adding whatever you have tried and provding the samples of input and expected output. You almost posted a ideal post, only thing missed is CODE TAGS, please do wrap your samples with code tags using `{}` button of your post(whch you did partially too, you need to cover al samples with it), keep learning and keep sharing on this GREAT site SO, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(it will show the number next to strings whichever OP mentioned to search for).

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

Or adding a non-one liner form of solution.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){
       val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)
    }
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
'   Input_file
```

In case you want to save output ito Input_fie itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code. Also in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and you want to have output as TAB delimited format then change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS="OFS="\t"}` keep from `{for....` code as it is as mentioned above.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program here.
{                                            ##Startig conditions BLOCK here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                        ##Starting a for lop here from variable i value 1 to till value of NF, where NF is awk OOTB variable and have value of number of fields in current line.
    if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){      ##Checking condition if current field value is startig with strings either updr OR udrl OR imgr OR imgl and ends with any of these then do following.
       val=(val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1))       ##Creating variable val whose value is keep concatenating its own previous value here.
    }                                        ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
  }                                          ##Closing BLOCK for for loop here.
  print val                                  ##Printing value of variable val here.
  val=""                                     ##Nullifying variable val value here.
}                                            ##Closing main BLOCK now.
'  Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***EDIT:*** Example of run of code.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}'  Input_file
48358.00 1015.00 523
48562.00 1169.00 523
48305.00 1210.00 523
48285.00 1135.00 523
48459.00 1210.00 523
48246.00 881.00 523
48439.00 1109.00 523
```

Comment: `$i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/` ?

Comment: @jhnc, thank you for letting me know the shortcut, changed solution now, thank you.

Comment: it's also a bugfix, `/updr/` matches `asdasdsupdrwqwewe`. :-) For efficiency, you could also do, `i++; val = ... $i; i++`

Comment: oops. second `i++` shouldn't be there. Idea is to skip the regexp check of the field after the current match (as we know that it can't)

Comment: @jhnc right and if we do that then while checking condition we need to do like `$(i-1)` which is more or less same thing :) cheers and thanks for improving answer.

Comment: getting error as awk: cmd. line:1: {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)} print val val="" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                   ^ ^syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)} print val val="" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: @vijayam, in one liner solution there was 1 extra `)` so removed it BOTH are working fine now, kindly do let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried this awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i" ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val O^C $(i+1):$(i+1)} print val;}' I do not see any extra braces.Can you please post the regular exp again which is working for you.

Comment: @jhnc why we have to nullify a variable val here.

Comment: @vijayam, both codes are working for me, did you copy them properly? `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}'  Input_file` try this? On Nullifying variables why I am doing is so that we make sure everytime new value of it is printing(not printing somehow old value).

Comment: Thanks guys the above logic is working here is my updated command which i was looking echo `awk ' BEGIN {OFS="," ;print "UpdateRate,UpdateLenght,ImgeRate,ImageLength"} /updr/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|updl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}' client_stat.txt > client_stat_onlyData.csv`

Comment: @vijayam, Glad that it helped you, you could select this answer as correct one too, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
 perl -ne ' while( /(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)\s+(\S+)/g ) { print "$2 " } print "\n" '  file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat vijaya.txt
updr    48358.00        updl    120     imgr    1015.00 imgl    523
updr    48562.00        updl    120     imgr    1169.00 imgl    523
updr    48305.00        updl    121     imgr    1210.00 imgl    523
updr    48285.00        updl    121     imgr    1135.00 imgl    523
updr    48459.00        updl    121     imgr    1210.00 imgl    523
updr    48246.00        updl    120     imgr    881.00  imgl    523
updr    48439.00        updl    120     imgr    1109.00 imgl    523

$ perl -ne ' while( /(updr|udrl|imgr|imgl)\s+(\S+)/g ) { print "$2 " } print "\n" ' vijaya.txt
48358.00 1015.00 523
48562.00 1169.00 523
48305.00 1210.00 523
48285.00 1135.00 523
48459.00 1210.00 523
48246.00 881.00 523
48439.00 1109.00 523

$
```

Comment: I am looking a command using shell script ...Thanks for your solution in perl it may helpful to others too.

Comment: @ please share a working command in shell script. Still i did not able to crack it.

Comment: It is working with the same logic above only thing is output in the file is after so many lines not at the beginning of the file                
49368.00 121 845.00 523
48542.00 121 1170.00 523    echo `awk 'BEGIN {print "UpdateRate,UpdateLenght,ImgeRate,ImageLength"} { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|updl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}' client_stat.txt > client_stat_onlyData.csv`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help here is the final command which i was looking to print o/p echo `awk ' BEGIN {OFS="," ;print "UpdateRate,UpdateLenght,ImgeRate,ImageLength"} /updr/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^(updr|updl|imgr|imgl)$/){val=val?val OFS $(i+1):$(i+1)}};print val;val=""}' client_stat.txt > client_stat_onlyData.csv`